# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'collop'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following directory:
backend

- api

  - serializers.py
- base

  - models.py

I try to import the module models.py in serializers.py by doing

```
from collop.base import models
```

I also tried

```
from backend.collop.base import models
```

and also other combinations but no one works.
It always sais 'No module named 'collop'/'backend''
I am using Python 3.8.5

I would be thankful for help!

Comment: did you pip install

Comment: Do you have __init__.py in each directory?

Comment: @frozen yes, when I ask for pip version it sais me >> pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: @DawidGacek yes I have them in every directory

Comment: This can be helpful to understand imports in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 1):

```
I also faced the same problem...
```

**my project structure**

```
- pyimports

    - api
    
        - serializers.py
   - base
        - models.py
```

**serializers.py**

```
def add(x,y):
  return x+y
```

**models.py**

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(1, 'L:/pyimports/api')

from serializers import add

print(add(3,4))
```

*copy the path location of the importing package. In your case copy path location of api folder*

```
sys.path.insert(1, 'copied path')
```

**Note:**

*if you are using windows use '/' in path*

*in Linux use 'backwards slash' in path*